# How Spring BOOT Logger Actuator behaves in clustered environment?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, scalability, spring-boot-actuator

I have a query related to Spring Boot Actuator.  Through Actuator I can change the log level dynamically.

In clustered environment how it works?

If I do the REST (POST) call to change the log level then in which node it will be applied?

Or will it be applied to all the nodes?

If it gets applied to all the nodes in the cluster then how to restrict it to only a  particular node?

Answer (score 3):

You should use external configuration server (spring cloud config) and use spring cloud bus to reflect configuration changes into all the servers of your cluster.

Place your log configuration on the configuration server, on each change, a message will be sent to a message broker (like rabbitMq) to all the servers listening to the config.

Comment: For a particular class I would like to change the log level "DEBUG" and I don't want it to be in all the nodes. How is it possible to set it for one node?
Doing a POST call to do it. Like....

curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel": "DEBUG"}' http://myapplication.com/actuator/loggers/com.my.app.classname

Comment: Hello, I misread your question.
There is no built in system that will replicate your configuration across each node. So if you don't need it, forget what I write about spring-cloud-bus. And do what you just said.